# Edit variables and use another class (Kotlin)

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-adapter

Please help, the program not work.
I want to change the variables a and b and put them in the names
Thanks..............................................................................................

```
class Asd(){
        lateinit var a: String
        lateinit var b: String
        var database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("RedCars")
            .child("20-8-2020 18:0")
            .addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
                override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

                }

                override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                    var map = p0.value as Map<String, Any>

                a = map["price"].toString()
                 b = map["pickup"].toString()
            }

        })
}


public class MyCustomAdapter(context: Context): BaseAdapter(){

    private val mContext: Context

    val d = Asd().a
    val h = Asd().b
    var names = arrayListOf<String>(
        d, h
    )
```

I try this:.............

```
 public class MyCustomAdapter(context: Context): BaseAdapter(){

    lateinit var a: String
    lateinit var b: String
    var database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("RedCars")
        .child("20-8-2020 18:0")
        .addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

            }

            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                var map = p0.value as Map<String, Any>
                
                a = map["price"].toString()
                b = map["pickup"].toString()
            }

        })

    private val mContext: Context

    var names = arrayListOf<String>(
        a, b
    )
```

Logcat error:....................................................

```
2020-08-05 22:03:16.024 9227-9227/com.example.redcars E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.redcars, PID: 9227
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.redcars/com.example.redcars.MainActivity}: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property a has not been initialized
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3895)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4074)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:91)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:149)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:103)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2473)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8347)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1055)
 Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property a has not been initialized
    at com.example.redcars.MainActivity$MyCustomAdapter.<init>(MainActivity.kt:133)
    at com.example.redcars.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:47)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8085)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8073)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1320)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3868)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4074) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:91) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:149) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:103) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2473) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8347) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1055)
```

And this have in MainActivity:

```
listView.adapter = MyCustomAdapter(this)
```

Comment: Can you please include any logs of errors, and the actual output of your code so that it is easier for us to have a whole picture of your issue.

Comment: I edited the post

Comment: To me it looks like because you've defined database in a variable, it's code is never run, and you're accessing the a and b variable before initialization, if you tried `val d = Asd()` then on the next line `d.database` then next line `d.a` you might fix the issue for the first use, the other case may be that there has been 0 changes in the database since init of the class, so it never received a value. Nullable miight be better for that case.

Comment: Does not recognize the database     |    

`public class MyCustomAdapter(context: Context): BaseAdapter(){

        private val mContext: Context



        val d = Asd()
        d.database
        d.a
        var names = arrayListOf<String>(
            a
        )`

Comment: You cant reference values in a class body in that manner, you would want to do it in an init block like: `init {
 d.database 
 d.a
 }`

Comment: it doesn't work that way either


`private val mContext: Context

        val d = Asd()

        init {
            d.database
            d.a
            mContext = context
        }`

Logcat: Unresolved reference: a

Comment: Why do you want to create ArrayList out of non-initialized variable? It is not supposed to be used unless it is initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `lateinit` properties only after they are initialized. So I suggest to move initialization of `names` array to `ValueEventListener`:

```
public class MyCustomAdapter(context: Context): BaseAdapter(){

    lateinit var a: String
    lateinit var b: String
    lateinit var names: ArrayList<String>

    // or you can use MutableList
    // var namesMutable: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()


    var database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("RedCars")
        .child("20-8-2020 18:0")
        .addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

            }

            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                var map = p0.value as Map<String, Any>
                
                a = map["price"].toString()
                b = map["pickup"].toString()

                // INITIALIZE THE ARRAY HERE

                names = arrayListOf<String>(a, b)
                // namesMutable.add(a)
                // namesMutable.add(b)
                // notifyDatasetChanged()
            }

        })

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Not work

Logcat:
`kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property names has not been initialized`

Comment: Please Help :D.

Comment: where do you use `names` array?

Comment: The ListView Adapter.
Because i want the firebase listView with many data for realtime database.

Comment: Please see my edited answer: you can try to use `MutableList` type instead of `ArrayList`